# const and non-const function overloading

Tags: c#, java, constants, overloading

We have `const` and non-`const` function overloading in C++ as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251159/what-is-the-use-of-const-overloading-in-c) and used in STL iterators.

Do we have such method overloading in Java and C#?

Comment: heyy you got `Jon Skeet` answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java and C# don't have the concept of const functions, so the concept of overloading by const/non-const doesn't really apply.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the prompt clarification :)

Answer (score 3):

C# unfortunately does not support const methods or const parameters.
There is a new feature in C# 2.0 that somewhat helps in a similar scenario. With C#2.0 get and set accessors of a property can be of different accessibility. So you can make the get accessor public and the set protected as follows

```
class MyClass

{

int _val;



    public int Val
   {
         protected set { _val = value; }

         get { return _val; }

   }

}
```

Comment: Or in C# 3... `public int Val { get; protected set; }`