# Doesn't compiler give an ambiguous error for "const" and "not-const" functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, c++14, constants

I have overloaded `const` and `non-const` functions in c++ structure. Then, I have run the program and I wondered, it's working fine without ambiguous error.

```
#include <iostream>

struct St 
{
  int f() const 
  { 
      return 1; 
  }

  int f()
  { 
      return 2;
  }
} s;

int main() 
{
    int ret = s.f();  
    std::cout<<ret<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, I just want to know, Why doesn't the compiler give an ambiguous error  for "const" and "not-const" functions?

Comment: [duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [const overloading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-overloading), which is [a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251159/what-is-the-use-of-const-overloading-in-c) in C++.

In this case, the compiler determines the struct does NOT have an overloaded function return type, (which is [disallowed due to ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type) of course) but rather an overloaded function with different “constness;” a term in one of the other answers which makes sense here.

As for getting no compiler errors:

1. const overloading is part of the C++ specification, so no errors
2. At compile-time, the compiler “sees” that the struct is returning to a non-const environment, so uses the non-const function, causing a normal operation to happen

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

### First an informal explanation

Let's take it in logical steps.

A non-const method is allowed and assumed to change the object. As such it can be called on non-const objects only.

A const method is not allowed to change the object. As such it can be called on const objects, but also on non-const objects.

When both overloads of a functions are defined (const and non-const) the method chosen is the one whose constness fits the object constness.

### The standard

In reality overload resolution has no special rule for const and non-const methods. Instead, the standard specifies an implicit object parameter. After you take into consideration this implicit object parameter, you can apply the usual overload resolution rules:

> §13.3.1 Candidate functions and argument lists [over.match.funcs]
>
> 2. [...] a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the implicit object parameter , which represents the object for
>      which the member function has been called. For the purposes of
>      overload resolution, both static and non-static member functions have
>      an implicit object parameter, but constructors do not.
> 3. Similarly, when appropriate, the context can construct an argument list that contains an implied object argument to denote the object to
>      be operated on. Since arguments and parameters are associated by
>      position within their respective lists, the convention is that the
>      implicit object parameter, if present, is always the first parameter
>      and the implied object argument, if present, is always the first
>      argument.
> 4. For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
>    - (4.1) “lvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared without a ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier
>    - (4.2) “rvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared with the && ref-qualifier
>
> where X is the class of which the function is a member and cv is the
>   cv-qualification on the member function declaration. [ Example: for a
>   const member function of class X, the extra parameter is assumed to
>   have type “reference to const X”. —end example ] For conversion
>   functions, the function is considered to be a member of the class of
>   the implied object argument for the purpose of defining the type of
>   the implicit object parameter. For non-conversion functions introduced
>   by a using-declaration into a derived class, the function is
>   considered to be a member of the derived class for the purpose of
>   defining the type of the implicit object parameter. [...]
>
> 5. **During overload resolution, the implied object argument is indistinguishable from other arguments**

Answer (score 2):

Assume that every member function of class `A` has an implicit parameter that is `const A&` for a const member function and `A&` for a non-const member function. Your member functions in the context of overload resolution process will look like:

```
int f(const St&); 
int f(St&);
```

If it is possible for overload resolution to choose the appropriate member than there is no ambiguity. This specific case is regulated in

> 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank]
>   Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>   ...
>   13.3.3.2/(3.2.6) `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings, and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2` refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by `S1` refers.

Thus, overload resolution process chooses the non-const member (as less cv-qualified).

Comment: Technically this isn't a qualification conversion (that term refers to non-top-level qualification changes); the rule in C++14 is [over.ics.rank]/3.1.6 "S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers."

Comment: @M.M, Thanks! Added to the answer